# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c0006

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

Starting from January 24, 2024, we have received android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c0006 crash problem from online users. Is this crash caused by any update operation done by Chrom? How should we fix it?

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c0006
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:255)
   at android.content.res.MiuiResourcesImpl.getValue(MiuiResourcesImpl.java:96)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1243)
   at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.isTablet(chromium-TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-616716433:9)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:340)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:169)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8301)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:577)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1076)
```

At present, it seems to be a problem in all versions. In about 60% of cases, it occurs in the background.

Comment: Due you have DynamicFeature in your project?

Comment: Catched same error today in our logs. Not using DynamicFeatures. Is it specific to that Android System WebView version (TrichromeWebViewGoogle6432.aab-stable-616716433)? @wenjie-ma did you found RC?

Comment: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/326260434

Comment: Did you find any RC/solution ?? having same crashed in bulk.. :/